# ThreadLocal Memory Leak in Icefaces 1.8 webapp using Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, memory-leaks, icefaces

We've managed to get rid of nearly all our memory leak error messages but we're stuck with this last one.

Jun 10, 2014 3:36:15 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$1] (value [com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$1@7066db4a]) and a value of type [com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate] (value [com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate@70c710ec]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

After investigation, we think it is the long polling thread mechanism that is causing the problem when Tomcat is stopped after a request is initialised but before it is destroyed (in com.sun.faces.application.WebappLifecycleListener).  Has anybody been able to get rid of this message?  I see it is commonly present in logs that have been included with questions asking about Tomcat and memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this message means to file the bug with Icefaces and wait for a fix.